# Remove input by clicking times icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have the following code which adds divs within a container (#subtask_container) via clicking a link (similar to Google Tasks):

HTML:

```
<p class="text-muted">
    <i class="fas fa-tasks mr-2"></i>
    <a href="#" id="add_subtask">Add subtasks</a>
</p>
<div id="subtask_container"></div>
```

JS (this successfully adds unique inputs within the subtask container div along with a clickable x after each input)

```
var i = 1
      $("#add_subtask").click(function () {
  $("#subtask_container").append('<input name="subtask'+i+'" class="mt-1" id="subtask'+i+'" placeholder="Enter subtask"><i class="fas fa-times ml-1 text-muted"></i><br>');
        i++;
});
```

What logic do I need to add to the x class to remove it's associated input?

I've tried

```
$('.fa-times').click(function(){
        $(this).prev('input').remove();
      });
```

but it doesn't seem to work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `wrap` your `subtask` `append` in a `div` and simply use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and `.remove()` function on that. No need to use `<br>`

Also, do not use `.fa-times` as primary `click` event handler as you might have other `fa-times` on the same page as well Which might cause issues later on. Add a custom class to your `fa` item *(.subtask_remove_icon)*

**Live Demo:**

```js
var i = 1
$("#add_subtask").click(function() {
  $("#subtask_container").append('<div><input name="subtask' + i + '" class="mt-1" id="subtask' + i + '" placeholder="Enter subtask"><i class="fas fa-times ml-1 text-muted subtask_remove_icon"></i></div>');
  i++;
});

$(document).on('click', '.subtask_remove_icon', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove(); //remove the input when X clicked
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<p class="text-muted">
  <i class="fas fa-tasks mr-2"></i>
  <a href="#" id="add_subtask">Add subtasks</a>
</p>
<div id="subtask_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The event handler gets attached to all elements that are on the page load. Since the icons are appended, the right way to do this would be the following:

```js
var i = 1
$("#add_subtask").click(function () {
  $("#subtask_container").append('<div><input name="subtask'+i+'" class="mt-1" id="subtask'+i+'" placeholder="Enter subtask"><i class="fas fa-times ml-1 text-muted removeIcon"></i><br></div>');
  i++;
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeIcon', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<p class="text-muted">
    <i class="fas fa-tasks mr-2"></i>
    <a href="#" id="add_subtask">Add subtasks</a>
</p>
<div id="subtask_container"></div>
```

Comment: This works great, save for 1 minor issue. Any idea on how I might be able to remove the <br /> tag as well? The removal is leaving a bunch of empty footer space behind.

Comment: @user882134 you can wrap the appended part in a ``div`` and remove the ``parent`` of the clicked icon. Answer updated.

Comment: @MajedBadawi Yeah thats already exactly answered above in my answer. No worries.